# Expose environment (hosted on Docker) both on localhost and Ngrok

Tags: plugins, configuration

I'm attempting to develop a WordPress blog together with a friend of mine.
For this purpose, I setup a docker-compose environment, with this docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

volumes:
    mysite_wordpress_content:
    mysite_mysql_data:
    
services:
  mysite_mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"    
    volumes:
      - mysite_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  mysite_wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - mysite_mysql
    image: wordpress:6.3.2
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    volumes:
      - mysite_wordpress_content:/var/www/html/wp-content

    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysite_mysql:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

So far, so good: I can work on my WordPress site on http://localhost:8181 .

Now I would like to let my friend access my site using ngrok.
For this purpose, I launch ngrok with the following command:

```bash
docker run -it --net=host -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=<myToken> ngrok/ngrok http 8181
```

Browsing the url shown by ngrok (something like https://.ngrok-free.app/), it seems to correctly access my server, but it (my WordPress server) responds with a "301 Moved Permanently" error message.

I notice a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64405968/how-to-use-ngrok-tunnels-correctly-for-best-workflow-with-wordpress-and-docker-c, but no provided solution seems to work.
I also tried to install some WordPress plugins, such as **relative-url**, **WPMultiHost** and **WP-ngrok**, but I had no luck with any of them.

How ngrok or Wordpress should be configured?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it working, by:

1. installing the [relative-url](https://sparanoid.com/work/relative-url/)  WordPress plugin
2. forcing ngrok to set the host header:

```bash
docker run -it --net=host -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=<myToken> ngrok/ngrok http --host-header=127.0.0.1:8181 8181
```